# Which value use with _trackEvent to monitor retention / cohorts?

Tags: events, google-analytics, tracking

I want to monitor mobile application, basically one page application. To do this I am going to use Google Analytics and add Events for user interactions.

With Google Analytics you have 5 values you can send to Google Analytics (http://goo.gl/6Gs4b)

- category
- action
- label
- value
- non-interaction

With every Event I want also send group identification. It will be basically something like Week 1, Week 2, Week 3.

I am not sure which of `_trackEvent` values would be best for monitoring groups. Not just add value but also be able to track by groups and see differences by groups.

So if I have:

```
_trackEvent('login', 'success', 'week 1');
_trackEvent('login', 'error', 'week 1');
```

Would I be able to monitor login success rate for week 1, week 2, week 3 and so on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application acts like one page, it might be worth it for you to configure hits as virtual pageviews instead of events. Then you're not limited in the number of parameters.

Example:

`_trackPageview('/login/success/week-1');`

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "group" though - maybe you'd benefit by a visitor level custom variable? That'll set each "Week" group with a cookie so you can segment any report by group.